# Wordpress proper way of adding pages

Tags: wordpress, static

I have been trying to figure this out now for a while but there but I haven't found any conclusive answer yet. I want to add some pages to wordpress that are static. I need to include JS script that is from a third-party login. Using JS, HTML, CSS. Very simple and basis login.

So normally what I do is create a page, empty, attach a template and put the JS/HTML/CSS/Text into that template.

However, it seems weird to create an empty page in a CMS. Is there another way, a proper way, of adding a normal page into wordpress without using the static PAGES option in the CMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create the page and add a link to it from your WP-site. But this is only if you don't need any of the wp-functions. Also it won't show up at all in your wp-admin dashboard.

Comment: Yeah, just upload `whatever.html` into the root folder, then you can link to `www.mysite.com/whatever.html`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I require the wordpress functions so then the only way apparently is by creating empty pages.